# Searching for groups of objects given a reduction function

Tags: sql, algorithm, search, prolog, logic

I have a few questions about a type of search.

First, is there a name and if so what is the name of the following type of search?  I want to search for subsets of objects from some collection such that a reduction and filter function applied to the subset is true.  For example, say I have the following objects, each of which contains an id and a value.

```
[A,10]
[B,10]
[C,10]
[D,9]
[E,11]
```

I want to search for "all the sets of objects whose summed values equal 30" and I would expect the output to be, `{{A,B,C}, {A,D,E}, {B,D,E}, {C,D,E}}`.

Second, is the only strategy to perform this search brute-force?  Is there some type of general-purpose algorithm for this?  Or are search optimizations dependent on the reduction function?

Third, if you came across this problem, what tools would you use to solve it in a general way?  Assume the reduction and filter functions could be anything and are not necessarily the sum function.  Does SQL provide a good API for this type of search?  What about Prolog?  Any interesting tips and tricks would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a "binary integer programming problem" (and a single equation) whereby a variable x_e exists for all element of your original set and it can take on value 0 or 1. The equation is then _"sum(x_e*weight_e) = constant"_

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment on the problem in general but brute forcing search can be easily done in prolog.

```
w(a,10).
w(b,10).
w(c,10).
w(d,9).
w(e,11).


solve(0, [], _).
solve(N, [X], [X|_]) :- w(X, N).
solve(N, [X|Xs], [X|Bs]) :-
    w(X, W),
    W < N,
    N1 is N - W,
    solve(N1, Xs, Bs).
solve(N, [X|Xs], [_|Bs]) :- % skip element if previous clause fails
    solve(N, [X|Xs], Bs).
```

Which gives

```
| ?- solve(30, X, [a, b, c, d, e]).
X = [a,b,c] ? ;
X = [a,d,e] ? ;
X = [b,d,e] ? ;
X = [c,d,e] ? ;
(1 ms) no
```

Answer (score 1):

Sql is TERRIBLE at this kind of problem.  Until recently there was no way to get 'All Combinations' of row elements.  Now you can do so with Recursive Common Table Expressions, but you are forced by its limitations to retain all partial results as well as final results which you would have to filter out for your final results.  About the only benefit you get with SQL's recursive procedure is that you can stop evaluating possible combinations once a sub-path exceeds 30, your target total.  That makes it slightly less ugly than an 'evaluate all 2^N combinations' brute force solution (unless every combination sums to less than the target total).

To solve this with SQL you would be running an algorithm that can be described as:

1. Seed your result set with all table entries less than your target total and their value as a running sum.
2. Iteratively join your prior result with all combinations of table that were not already used in the result set and whose value added to running sum is less than or equal to target total.  Running sum becomes old running sum plus value, and append ID to ID LIST.  Union this new result to the old results.  Iterate until no more records qualify.
3. Make a final pass of the result set to filter out the partial sums that do not total to your target.

Oh, and unless you make special provisions, solutions {A,B,C}, {C,B,A}, and {A,C,B} all look like different solutions (order is significant).